# Second order estimates for Dirichlet problem for complex Monge-Ampere equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, potential-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a bounded pseudo-convex domain. Let $0<f\in C^{\infty}(\bar\Omega)$, $\phi\in C^\infty(\partial \Omega)$. Consider the Dirichlet problem for the complex Monge -Ampere equation
\begin{eqnarray*}\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{\operatorname{det}}
\Det\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_i\partial \bar z_j}\right)=f,\\
u|_{\partial \Omega}=\phi,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $u\in C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ is plurisubharmonic.

It is well known that this problem has a unique solution, see L. Caffarelli, J.J. Kohn, L. Nirenberg, J. Spruck, The Dirichlet problem for nonlinear second order elliptic equations II. Complex Monge-Ampère and uniformly elliptic equations, Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 38 (1985), 209-252.

**Question.** I am trying to generalize to above result in certain direction, and the method of the above paper to get second order a priori estimates does not seem to work. **I am looking for other methods to get second order estimates, i.e. $\|u\|_{C^2}$.**